# free linked list that is inside a struct

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have an `ordinateur` of type `ordi`

```c
typedef struct ordi
{
    int numeroOrdi;
    char *nomOrdi;
    int CapaciteDisque;
    lst_logi LogicielsInstalles;
} ordi;
```

this `ordinateur` has a doubly linked list `LogicielsInstalles` of type `lst_logi`

```c
typedef struct lst_logi
{
    log *logiciel;
    struct lst_logi *next;
    struct lst_logi *prev;
} lst_logi;
```

I made a function `FormaterOrdinateur` to delete all "Logiciels"(Software in french)
In other word free the linked list `LogicielsInstalles`.

```c
void FormaterOridinateur(ordi *ordinateur)
{
    lst_logi *head = &ordinateur->LogicielsInstalles;
    lst_logi *tmp;

    // printf("curr: %s\n", head->logiciel->designation);
    // printf("curr->next: %s\n", (head->next)->logiciel->designation);
    // these two line to make sure the node and node->next exit 
    while (head)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
    ordinateur = NULL;
}
```

but this function gives me seg fault
more details with gdb:

```c
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e244c9 in arena_for_chunk (ptr=0x7fffffffe051) at ./malloc/arena.c:156
156     ./malloc/arena.c: No such file or directory.
```

when I searched about `arena_for_chunk` error I found out that it means memory doesn't exist or can't be freed
I'm sure the node I'm trying to free exists so it just refuses to be freed. 
any explanation for that. And how can I fix it.
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: There's a problem with the way you build your list — and you've not shown that code, which makes it hard to debug it.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Then show us an MCVE that reproduces the problem, including enough data.  (Note that a stack backtrace would help identify which line in your code triggers the crash.)

Comment: Note that the line `ordinateur = NULL;` does nothing useful.  It sets the function's local copy of the pointer to null without affecting the calling code in the slightest.  This might mean you are freeing data a second time.  It also appears that you are not freeing the `nomOrdi` member of the structure; that will probably lead to a memory leak.

Comment: Your `lst_logi` is a struct type. I'm pretty sure that your list's head node `LogicielsInstalles` should be a pointer to a list node `lst_logi`, not a node.

Comment: true it should be a pointer. nice I'll check that out @MOehm.
edit: fixing it gave me hundreds of errors xd, I have to change some things

Comment: @AzerSD Who owns the `log` elements pointed out by the `lst_logi` nodes? Are they stored somewhere else to be free'd separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `struct ordi`, `LogicielsInstalles` should be a pointer, not a structure to account for computers with no installed software, and avoid an invalid `free` on `&ordinateur->LogicielsInstalles`.

Furthermore, your function `FormaterOrdinateur` does not reset the pointer `LogicielsInstalles` after freeing the list. It instead sets `ordinateur = NULL`, which has no effect as `ordinateur` is just a local argument value.

This may cause invalid access later or a double free.

Here is a modified version:

```
typedef struct lst_logi {
    log *logiciel;
    struct lst_logi *next;
    struct lst_logi *prev;
} lst_logi;

typedef struct ordi {
    int numeroOrdi;
    char *nomOrdi;
    int CapaciteDisque;
    lst_logi *LogicielsInstalles;
} ordi;

void FormaterOrdinateur(ordi *ordinateur) {
    lst_logi *node = ordinateur->LogicielsInstalles;

    while (node) {
        lst_logi *next = node->next;
        // free the log structure pointed to by node->logiciel
        free(node->logiciel);
        // free the node structure
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
    ordinateur->LogicielsInstalles = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps even `free(tmp->logiciel);` if those are owned by the `lst_logi` nodes too.

Comment: thanks a lot. my mistake was "In the struct ordi, LogicielsInstalles should be a pointer". and imagine 400 lines of code with such a stupid mistake.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `tmp->logiciel` `logiciel` is a struct of type `log`. do I have to free it too? so allways with freeing the pointer I should free the content?

Comment: @AzerSD Yes, you need one `free` for every `malloc` (or `calloc`)

Comment: If you allocate a `log` structure for each node, you should free it when you free the node.

Comment: perfect, Got it. @TedLyngmo & chqrilie thanks a lot <3